# Append query parameter to module's javascript based on custom field on page

Tags: 8, nodes

I am new to Drupal development.

I am currently working on maintaining a Drupal module that was developed by a past colleague.

What I want to do is have an available field where a user can enter in an integer which corresponds to a JS query parameter that will be added to one of the module's script upon page load.

I am wondering if it is possible to add a custom field type that users can add through the Drupal UI to their content (nodes), and then check for the existence of this field and append it to the script?

I have found this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/programming-custom-fields-into-your-content-type) helpful in adding custom fields through my module. However, it doesn't provide any links to documentation that specifies what values I can/should put on dependencies, module, along with other parameters. Also after quite a bit of Google searching, and a bit of combing through Drupal docs, I ended up with nothing.

Further, I believe that I am more or less on the right track in using the `hook_page_attachments_alter` function to check against fields and conditionally load JS scripts. Although, I don't believe that the `$page` array passed through this hook supplies node fields.

Currently the module is loading the custom JS like so:

```
  function my_module_page_attachments_alter(&$page) {

    $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/script';

  }
```

Obviously it is loading it through libraries, which would make appending a custom query string parameter difficult. Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to approach this through [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.4.x). It's easy enough to get the current node in the page attachments hook, but as you only need to take action when a node is being viewed, using the more specific hook seems appropriate.

A basic example:

```
function my_module_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full' && $entity->getType() == 'foo' && $entity->hasField('field_bar')) {
    if ( ($val = $entity->field_bar->value) ) {
      $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/script';
      $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['my_module']['script']['bar'] = $val;
    }
  }
}
```

The settings you add to the `#attached` array will be available in JS after a change to your libraries yml file to add a dependency:

```
script:
  js:
    ...
  dependencies:
    ...
    - core/drupalSettings
```

The value will be available in the JS var `drupalSettings.my_module.script.bar`.

Comment: This is a great answer. Apologies, because I actually just figured out that I miss-read the code, and the dev actually was attaching a framework array to $page['#attached']['html_head'][] which contained the url that I needed to append to. So I was able to just pull in the current node and append the field parameter. 

I'll leave this up, however, because I think this could definitely help others out running into similar problems.

Comment: @AveryKushner, it's better to attach node specific things in a node or in your case if you have a custom field formatter it might be even better to attach it there when it depends on how the field is configured. Attachments bubble up to the page level automatically.